# Долго выполняющаяся процедура postgres в java приложении. ConnectionTimeout

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, jdbc, хранимые-процедуры

Есть хранимая процедура, которая может выполняться в течении нескольких часов.

Данная ХПшка вызывается из java приложения. Timeout в настройках выставлен на полторы минуты, соответственно, когда ответ не приходит через полторы минуты, мы падаем с таймаутом и все откатывается.

Были всевозможные попытки локально у dataSource, JdbcTemplate выставить таймауты (-1), что не помогло для конкретного соединения. Попытка использовать StoredProcedure с неограниченным таймаутом тоже провалилась.

Возможно кому то уже приходилось сталкиваться с подобной проблемой. Возможно решение просто вызова этой функции без ожидания ответа, но нужного метода не обнаружено.

**UPD:** ERROR: `org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: CallableStatementCallback; SQL [{? = call function_name()}]; ERROR: canceling statement due to user request`

Comment: Может быть поможет аннотация `@Async` над методом, в котором вызывается запрос к ХП?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, находил тред на эту тему, но нет. Не помогло. И данная аннотация не решает проблемы закрытия соединения.

Comment: Не очень понятно из описания. То есть значение настраиваемого таймаута подхватывается ? Если выставить две минуты , отвалится через две или нет ? И стектрейс ошибки приложите.

Comment: @c0ld, Значение таймаута при ручном выставлении не подхватывается. Ошибка: `postgresql error: canceling statement due to user request`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114101/postgresql-error-canceling-statement-due-to-user-request

Comment: @c0ld, к сожалению, я это видел и решение не помогло.